# Calculating size of small magnetic particles from a hysteresis curve

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

Let's say that you have ferromagnetic particles dispersed in a medium (solid, diamagnetic) - can you calculate the sizes of particles from the hysteresis curve. Or if not then from the first magnetization (from zero magnetization to max magnetization).

I know that using the Langevin model you can calculate the mean size of particles that are in superparamagnetic state. But obviously you cannot  use this method to calculate the size of particles of a ferromagnetic state. Right? So is it possible?